# When using insertHtml extra whitespace appears before content in Word online

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

Calling `insertHtml(content, "Replace")` adds whitespace before the inserted content in Word Online.
This whitespace is not present when running the same code in Word on Windows or Mac.

This can easily be reproduced by running the following code on a document that contains
hyperlinks:

```ts
    context.document.body
      .getRange()
      .getHyperlinkRanges()
      .getFirst()
      .insertHtml("Test", "Replace");
```

An example of such an document linked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9ojH.png).
Image shows a document with text `Video provides` where `_vides_` in `provides` is a link.

Running the code above will result in:
`Video pro Test` in Word Online
`Video proTest` in Word Mac and Windows

Notice that Word Online result adds extra whitespace

```
Video pro Test
         ^ extra whitespace not present on other platforms
```

The expected behaviour would be for all platforms to result 
with `Video proTest`. Is there a way to get the expected 
behaviour on all platforms?

Gist with Script Lab code available [here](https://gist.github.com/josip-rc/5d053ac70d53858dcfa16861ac56d9d7)